# LINQ Select with multiple tables fields being writeable

Tags: linq, readonly

I'm new to LINQ and I'm doing pretty well until now, but now stuck with this.

I've a LINQ object bounded to a DataGridView to let the user edit is contains.
for simple one table query, it go fine, but how to build a LINQ query with multiple table, so the result will still be read/write?

Here a example of what I mean:

```
    GMR.Data.GMR_Entities GMR = new GMR.Data.GMR_Entities();

    var dt = from Msg in GMR.tblMessages
             join lang in GMR.tblDomVals on 1 equals 1//on Msg.pLangueID equals lang.ID
             select Msg;
             //   select new {lang.DescrFr, Msg.Message,Msg.pLangueID } ;

    this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

In this simple query, if I return only "Msg" with the select statement, the grid can be edited. But if I replace the select statement with  select new {lang.DescrFr, Msg.Message,Msg.pLangueID } ; the grid will be readable only.
I can easily understand that this is due because the query result is a anonymous type.
But is there a way to let the table tblMessage being writable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try creating your own class, for example

```
public class MsgLangInfo
{
 public string langDescFr{get;set;}
 public int pLangueID{get;set;}
}
```

And at the `select` statement create an object of this class with `new` like below

```
select new MsgLangInfo { 
                         langDescFr = lang.DescrFr, 
                         langDescFr = Msg.Message,Msg.pLangueID 
                       } ;
```

This way you can avoid the anonymous type problem.

Comment: That won't modify the original table.

Comment: @SLaks I may have misunderstood the problem then, thanks for the warning.

Answer (score 0):

You need to select the originals rows and explicitly set the grid columns.